# Django Tastypie - Why does Tastypie object authorization not work?

Tags: django, tastypie

I am new to Django and Tastypie and trying to work out how the API authorization works following the documentation [here](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authorization.html#implementing-your-own-authorization).

As far as i can tell it does not work. When I make a POST request to an object NOT owned by the request user it returns true when it should not (i haven't tried DELETE or PUT but I imagine it is the same).

Either I have implemented it wrong (probable) or there is a bug. So the question is: How do i implement object authorization with the code example below? For example, I want only the *Owner* of *Stock* to be able to POST a *Comment* or *Note* on that *Stock*.

This is the `book/models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid

class Stock(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the stock info.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book_code = models.CharField(max_length=14, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_code

class Note(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the stock note.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=560)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    date_note_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.note

class Comment(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing a Comment for each stock.
    '''
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    comment_author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.id)
```

This is the `api/api.py`:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from book.models import Stock, Note, Comment
from tastypie.authentication import ApiKeyAuthentication
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie import fields

class StockAuthorization(Authorization):

    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.filter(user=bundle.request.user)

class NoteAuthorization(Authorization):

    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.filter(user=bundle.request.user)

    def create_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        return obj.thought_author == bundle.request.user

class CommentAuthorization(Authorization):

    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.filter(user=bundle.request.user)

    def create_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        return obj.thought_author == bundle.request.user


class StockResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Stock.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'stock'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        authorization = StockAuthorization()
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()

    #ensure object is associated with user who makes a POST request
    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.obj.user = bundle.request.user
        return bundle

class NoteResource(ModelResource):
    stock = fields.ForeignKey(StockResource, attribute='stock', null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Note.objects.all()
        fields = ['user', 'note', 'stock', 'date_note_created']
        resource_name = 'note'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        authorization = NoteAuthorization()
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.obj.user = bundle.request.user
        return bundle


class CommentResource(ModelResource):

    stock = fields.ForeignKey(StockResource, attribute='stock', null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Comment.objects.all()
        fields = ['text', 'date']
        resource_name = 'comment'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        authorization = CommentAuthorization()
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()


    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.obj.comment_author = bundle.request.user
        return bundle
```

Comment: What is `obj` in your `create_detail`s?

Comment: [https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources) this may help too

Comment: Thanks MJafar Mash and apologies for the belated reply. When i saw the link you posted i was over the moon as it seemed to be what i needed. Alas, upon implementing it, i still have the same problem: any user can push to any object.